# Como executar um arquivo php atraves de um Switch Button com html e css?

Tags: php, html, css

Salve pessoal!! Sou novato no universo de programação. Gostaria de saber como fazer este botão executar um arquivo em .php acionado e outro arquivo .php quando não acionado.

```css
/* Estilo iOS */
.switch__container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 120px;
}

.switch {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
}

.switch + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.switch--shadow + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
.switch--shadow + label:before,
.switch--shadow + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
.switch--shadow + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.switch--shadow + label:after {
  width: 62px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.switch--shadow:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
.switch--shadow:checked + label:after {
  transform: translateX(60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch__container">
  <input id="switch-shadow" class="switch switch--shadow" type="checkbox">
  <label for="switch-shadow"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá fazer a requisição do arquivo `PHP` via `Ajax` ao trocar o valor do `switch`.

Você pode usar:

```
<input id="switch-shadow" name="switch-btn" class="switch switch--shadow" type="checkbox">
```

E no `JQuery`:

```
// quando estado do switch for alterado
$('input[name = switch-btn').change(function()
{
    // variavel indica script PHP a ser executado
    var pagina = '';

    // se está ligado seta um script, se nao seta outro
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        pagina = "ligado .php";
    else
        pagina = "desligado.php"

    // AJAX faz requisição no script, caso nunca usou ajax, saiba
    // que ele aguada um retorno do PHP, seja um echo ou algo assim
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: pagina, // script PHP
        type: 'POST ou GET', // metodo (caso tenha de enviar dados ao script)
        data:  seus-dados, // dados a enviar, caso tenha
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data", // caso for enviar arquivo
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            // se houve sucesso ao contatar pagina php ou coletar retorno
            // a variavel data é o seu retorno do PHP
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            // Em caso de erro
        }          
    });
});
```

Comment: Note que ele deseja executar 2 tipos de funções, uma ao ser ativado e outra ao ser desativado. "um arquivo em .php acionado e outro arquivo .php quando não acionado".

Comment: Sim sim, acabei de adicionar na resposta, obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: Desde já agradeço a ajuda, tentei fazer aqui porem não funcionou. Acho que fiz alguma coisa errada. Coloquei o seu codigo no index.html e os arquivos em .php no servidor local, porem os arquivos nao são carregados.

Comment: Como colocou em .php? Não coloquei código php na resposta, o primeiro trecho de código é o botão, o segundo é o `javascript` que vai no fim da página html, sugiro que pesquise mais sobre o assunto pois isso faz parte de noções básicas.